# Why does my C program crash when I try to realloc() a pointer array of structs?

Tags: c, struct, malloc, realloc

In the code below, I'm trying to expand an array of key value structs using realloc().

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct {
    char key[25];
    char value[25];
} keyValPair;

void inputKeyVal(keyValPair* arr, int n) {
    char inputKey[25];
    char inputVal[25];
    printf("input key: ");
    scanf(" %24s", &inputKey);
    printf("input value: ");
    scanf(" %24s", &inputVal);
    n++;
    arr = (keyValPair*) realloc( (keyValPair*) arr, n*sizeof(keyValPair));
    strcpy(arr[n-1].key, inputKey);
    strcpy(arr[n-1].value, inputVal);
}

int main() {
    keyValPair initArr[] = {{"foo", "bar"}, {"a", "b"}};
    int n = sizeof(initArr)/sizeof(keyValPair);
    keyValPair* arr = malloc(n * sizeof(keyValPair));
    arr = initArr;
    inputKeyVal(arr, n);
}
```

Whenever I run it however, it runs up to the input prompt, before crashing at the realloc() attempt. I still can't figure out why or how to fix it. Fairly new to C, so a detailed explanation would be much appreciated and would go a long way.

Comment: InitArr is allocated on the stack in main(). You can’t realloc that. You have to malloc it, as you do with the first arr (that you then throw away without freeing).

Comment: Also, you change inputKeyVal's `arr`, but you never change `main`'s, so any use of `arr` after the call to `inputKeyVal` will be wrong.

Comment: `keyValPair* arr = malloc(n * sizeof(keyValPair)); arr = initArr;` This is wrong, you're creating a memory leak. After `arr = malloc(..)`, `arr` points to some memory (unless `malloc` fails). When you do `arr = initArr`, you reassign `arr` to point to `initArr`. Now, nothing points to the memory you just allocated, so it can't be used or `free`d. Additionally as mentioned, now `arr` points to non-`realloc`able memory.

Comment: gekii_, `char inputKey[25]; .... scanf(" %24s", &inputKey);` implies your are compiling without all warnings enabled.  Save time, enable all warnings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that there are three problems.

`arr = initArr;` overwrites the address of `arr` by `initArr`, so that `realloc` can't take the address which has been allocated by `malloc`.
To keep the address allocated by `malloc`, the contents of `initArr` should be copied into `arr`.

```
#include <stddef.h>

for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(initArr) / sizeof(initArr[0]); i++) {
   arr[i] = initArr[i];
}
```

The last argument for `scanf` is wrong. `&` is unnecessary.

```
scanf("%24s", inputKey);
```

After `inputKeyVal`, `arr` at `main` loses valid address because it is reallocated in `inputKeyVal`.
If you require the correct address which has been reallocated by `realloc`, `inputKeyVal` should return the reallocated address.

```
keyValPair* inputKeyVal(keyValPair* arr, int n) {
  /* snipped */
  return arr;
}

int main() {
  /* snipped */
  arr = inputKeyVal(arr, n);
  /* do something for arr */
  free(arr);
  return 0;
}
```